# How to add title to a html file using perl HTML::Table

Tags: perl

I have created a html table using HTML::Table module, now I want to add a title to it. Please suggest me how to add title to the table without using CGI or any other modules.

```
#!/apps/perl/5.14.2/bin/perl
use strict;
use feature "say";
use HTML::Table;
use lib "/apps/perl/modules-1205/lib";

my $table= new HTML::Table( -cols       =>  18,
                            -align      =>  'left',
                            -border     =>  1,
                            -width      =>  '50%',
                            -spacing    =>  1,
                            -padding    =>  1,
                            -bgcolor    => '#DFF7FE',
                          );

$table->addSectionRow('thead', 0,'Block Name','Owner','Handoff','Testpoints','Type','SA-Cov','SA-Cov-TP','SA-Cov-Diff','SA-Patt','SA-Patt-TP','SA-Patt-Diff','TFT-Cov','TFT-Cov-TP','TFT-Cov-Diff','TFT-Patt','TFT-Patt-TP','TFT-Patt-Diff','Path');

$table->setSectionStyle('thead', 0, 'background-color: #FFFEEC');
$table->setSectionRCellsHead('thead', 0, 1);

open my $HTML,'>' ,'Testpoint.html' or die $!;
print $HTML "$table\n";
```

Comment: Depending on what you mean by title, there's the `setCaption()` method...

Comment: `HTML::Table` does not build a complete HTML file. To build a complete HTML object, you need something like `HTML::DOM`, and the output of HTML::Table object would be an element in the DOM.

Comment: As an aside, the [documentation for HTML::Table](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Table) uses "indirect object notation" to create its objects - which is presumably where you've copied it from. That's not a recommended approach (and hasn't been for a long time). You should use `my $table = HTML::Table->new(...)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do that with that module. [HTML::Table](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Table) literally only produces HTML `<table>` elements. It's not a general-purpose tool.

The easy approach will be to `print "<title>My Title</title>\n";` before printing the table. There's no reason to get another module involved.